# Statement from Bredon's Topology and Geometry

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology

On p. 346, he makes the statement[image]

By the asterisk he means the free product, as I found on page 150. What is he trying to say here? Taking $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$, we have ${}_2\mathbb{Z}/2 \approx \mathbb{Z}/2 \not \approx \mathbb{Z}/2 * \mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: Those two definitions of $G_2$ are inconsistent.  I think that instead of an asterisk, that should be a $\otimes$.

Comment: ...and $G* \mathbb{Z}_2$ isn't even abelian.